# How system know User camera Move event & custom "fly" back current location button

Tags: android

I just built my Android app with Google Map API and manage to have it run what I expect. But I still have some question to improve my UI.

Question 1 :
I want to hide softkeyboard  every time when user manually move the map (by swiping/taping on screen). I have a working hide soft keyboard function and i just want to call it when user move the screen.

Question2 :
I am using a custom "fly" back to current location, but it is ugly. I wish to have something like the default google's "fly"  button which actually have amination that "fly" back to current location instead of teleport back. Or it is good if i can move the default icon to bottom right.

here is a part of my code:

```
 private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

The "fly" button:

```
private void getDeviceLocation(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try{
        if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

            final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                        Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                        moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                   DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                   "My Location");

                    }else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                        Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
}

 mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: There is listener called ***OnCamerMoveListener*** which you can use to know when map moves and hide the keyboard.

Question 2: you can use ***animateCamera*** method instead of ***moveCamera*** to have that smooth transition.